# jave spring string equals return false when they seem to be the same when printing

Tags: java, string, spring, spring-mvc, equals

I'm working on an eclipse project using java spring for a website. However, no matter what I tried, the following string seems to be different. Would be great if someone can tell me what to do.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/result", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView execute(@ModelAttribute("dummyForm") final DummyForm dummyForm, final Model model) {
        // ...
        final String str = dummyForm.getFirstName() + "_" + dummyForm.getLastName();
        if(str.equals("Dummy_Smith")){
            // ...
        }
        return mav;
    }
```

with this code, when I test with dummyForm.setFirstName("Dummy") and dummyForm.setLastName("Smith"):
printing "str" in jsp will show "Dummy_Smith" as expected. But at the if condition check, it always returns false. 
I tried doing str.compareTo("Dummy_Smith"), and it returns -33. 
What should I do if I want it to return true?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: equals is not case insensitive

Comment: oh made a typo in the question. the cases for both strings should be the same.

Comment: Does that fix the problem?  If so, you probably want to delete the question - typos don't really add much value to the site :)

Comment: It didn't fix the problem

Comment: Why don't you debug it?

Comment: Due to the server I'm connecting the webapp to, I always get connection refused when i try debug, In other words, my debugger is not working. I would've done already if I could.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bet is that there are either whitespace or invisible characters in the string so that when you print it looks like they are the same string but they are not, actually, the same. Try to trim out any whitespace from the string you are comparing to and see what it returns:

```
String trimmed = str.trim();
System.out.println(trimmed);
System.out.println(trimmed.compareTo("Dummy_Smith"));
```

A `true` value from the `compareTo` call is if the value is equal to `0` (so the second printed line above).

Comment: Thank you so much it worked! It was some special character got carried in from the jsp form I submitted from.